# Como pegar uma resposta que está no header da requisição

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, react-hooks, http-headers

Estou fazendo um site que contem um fórum e preciso pegar a quantidade de tópicos e usuários cadastrados e com isso em meu back-end eu envio essas quantidades pelo header. Estou usando no meu back-end Cors, Express, Knex, Nodemailer, SQLite3.

```
async listAll(request, response){
    const { page = 1 } = request.query;
    const [count_topics] = await connection('topics')
    .count();
    const [count_users] = await connection('users')
    .count();
    const topics = await connection('topics')
    .join('users', 'users.id_user', '=', 'topics.user_id')
    .orderBy('id_topic', 'desc')
    .limit(3)
    .offset((page - 1) * 3)
    .select(['topics.id_topic', 'topics.title', 'topics.description', 'topics.date_topic', 'users.user']);
    const recent_topics = await connection('topics')
    .join('users', 'users.id_user', '=', 'topics.user_id')
    .orderBy('id_topic', 'desc')
    .limit(7)
    .offset((page - 1) * 7)
    .select(['topics.id_topic', 'topics.title', 'topics.date_topic', 'users.user']);
    response.header('X-Total-Count-Topics', count_topics['count(*)']); //aqui estou enviando a quantidade de tópicos pelo header
    response.header('X-Total-Count-Users', count_users['count(*)']); //aqui estou enviando a quantidade de usuarios cadastrados pelo header
    const send = {topics, recent_topics};
    return response.json(send);
}
```

E essas informações estão no cabeçalho conforme eu inseri.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está meu front-end feito em React onde eu tento pegar as informações que estão no header. Estou usando no meu front-end Axios, html-react-parser, react-router-dom, react-scripts, sweetalert2.

```
const [topics, setTopics] = useState([]);
const [recentTopics, setRecentTopics] = useState([]);
const [totalTopics, setTotalTopics] = useState(0);
const [totalUsers, setTotalUsers] = useState(0);
async function loadTopics() {
    const response = await api.get('/topics');
    setTopics(response.data.topics);
    setRecentTopics(response.data.recent_topics);
    setTotalTopics(response.headers['X-Total-Count-Topics']); //eu tentei pegar desse jeito mas aparece undefined
    setTotalUsers(response.headers['X-Total-Count-Users']); //eu tentei pegar desse jeito mas aparece undefined
}
useEffect(() => {
    loadTopics();
}, []);
```

Quando quando eu uso o que armazenei na state basicamente não aparece a quantidade de usuários e tópicos que está no cabeçalho, já coloquei um console.log() e ele aparece undefined.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria saber como é que eu pego esses dados que enviei para meu header para eu poder dar continuação em meu projeto.

Comment: Irei dar uma olhada mais tarde, mas você não pode passar essa informação no json do backend e recuperar ela no front? se puder e não souber como fazer é só falar que tento fazer um exemplo simples em código e ti mostro

Comment: da um console.log(response.headers) e console.log(response.data) e vê oque aparece se não estiver essas informações lá você esta tentando acessar da maneira errada, e fala oque esta aparecendo em Preview e Response

Answer (score 0):

Quanto aos headers deixa assim:

```
setTotalTopics(response.headers['x-total-count-topics']);
setTotalUsers(response.headers['x-total-count-users']);
```

Quanto aos outros dados leia meu comentário e post, precisamos de mais informações.

Answer (score 0):

Tenha em mente que para receber os headers ja deve ter a response, e ler eles como chaves no array, logo eles estarão lower case, ficaria assim:

```
response.headers['x-total-count-topics'] //4
response.headers['x-total-count-users'] //2
```

para ficar de melhor entendimento, basta usar o

```
console.log(response.headers['x-total-count-topics'])
console.log(response.headers['x-total-count-users'])
```

Na documentação abaixo está explicito que é necessario acessar os header com lower case

https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema